# Is the most (theoretically-) secure OS/distro something minimalistic like Gentoo or something security-focused like Qubes?

Tags: privacy, operating-systems

Assuming you only use mainstream software like Firefox, Thunderbird and Libreoffice, and update/upgrade every day and use strong passwords and encryption. I know this is probably a very basic and unprofessional question for this site, but I get mixed messages regarding what the best choice is for someone paranoid about government spying and all, despite the fact that computers already have black boxes, so you can't be 100% secure/private, but that you can at least do what you can.

Comment: FWIW I don't know if I'd consider Gentoo minimalistic. In my mind its main defining feature is its configurability. Sure, you can configure it to be fairly minimal, but you can also configure it to be a full-featured system with lots of software.

Comment: Right, but the fact that you can compile anything to only include what you need is a plus.

Answer (score 2):

> ... mainstream software like Firefox, Thunderbird and Libreoffice,

This is actually highly complex software, so bugs are likely.

> ...  and update/upgrade every day

Updating every day assumes that issues are fixed immediately after somebody has known about. In practice the attacker might actually know about a vulnerability before anybody else and thus can exploit it before anybody fixed it, i.e. a zero-day attack.
Of course updating is important but it does not prevent all attacks.

> ... something minimalistic like Gentoo or something security-focused like Qubes?

Qubes cares about more and stronger separation on the same computer.

If you just use plain Gentoo you likely run Firefox, Thunderbird and Libreoffice under the same account and all of these have access to your sensitive data. Proper use of Qubes instead means that you have stronger separation inside the computer, at least as long as you don't run the internet exposed Firefox in the same VM as a Libreoffice working with sensitive data. This way even a zero-day attack is restricted to the internet facing VM and has no access to the sensitive data in the other VM.

While you could achieve something similar with different user accounts on Gentoo the separation is less strict, (different user accounts provides less separation than different virtual machines) and maybe less comfortable to use too.
Of course, if you just run everything in the same VM then Qubes does not offer that much in additional security, but this is not how you are supposed to use it.

Comment: The point of Gentoo is that it is extremely configurable, much more than Qubes is. The maximum security you can achieve in Gentoo is far higher than the maximum security you can achieve with Qubes.

Comment: @forest: being extremely configurable does not necessarily mean better achievable security. I would argue that something designed with high security in mind from scratch is better than something generic which is just highly configurable. It's not the number of knobs one has to tune the system which makes it more or less secure but the internal design.

Comment: The internal design of Gentoo is extremely minimal. It's based entirely on being able to make changes, even invasive changes, to the point where Gentoo can be made into essentially any other distro if desired. Although something designed entirely from scratch kernel-up may be more secure.

Comment: @forest For most users, configurability hinders security (if they take advantage of it or if the defaults are suboptimal). Configurability means more risk of accidentally opening security holes. But, conversely, the problem with Qubes is that VMing each application hinders usability considerably.

Answer (score 1):

While you may be able to more finely tune a Gentoo, Yocto or Buildroot,  maybe even to a higher standard of security than Qubes.  If one fails to keep up with these mitigations, an updated Qubes will certainly be more secure on a long enough timeline.  There is a lot of value in the centralization of concerns to a community where the collective eyes and hands can maintain and take into consideration the effect of every patch to every piece of software.

But I guess if one got so frustrated maintaining a computer that they turned it off, unplugged it and never used it, it would certainly be the most secure computer.